# Java 1.7, APMHAL, sending a multiple argument command to CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I'm trying to send a command to a nother program APMHAL, which basically communicates with external hardwares. I need to send a command like "apmhalcli command1 parameter1"
than it succeeds. But if i try one like "apmhalcli command1 --parameter1 --parametr2"
it say that:
cannot run programme "......" error number = 2, there is no such file or directory

BUT, if i type the exact same command myself, in cli than it works. (So, if my java program sends it, than error, if i write it than it succeeds).

I tried these so far:

```
    String p1 = "command1 ";
    String p2 = "--parameter1 --parametr2";

    try {
        new ProcessBuilder(p1 + p2).start();
    } catch(IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(p1 + p2);
    } catch(IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any ideas, how to just insert the command to cli and simulate an "enter"? I've been trying for a couple of days now to get it working... Thank you for your time.

Edit: Here is what I implemented from your help and tried.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli", "openGate", "--module " + col, " --locker " + row);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("out1.txt"));
    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli openGate", "--module " + col, " --locker " + row);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("out2.txt"));
    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli", "openGate", "--module " + col + " --locker " + row);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("out3.txt"));
    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli openGate", "--module " + col + " --locker " + row);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("out4.txt"));
    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli openGate --module " + col + " --locker " + row);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("out5.txt"));
    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

number out1 and out3 recorded that only "apmhalcli openGate" was used, the later parts were ignored. The other variations just out right failed as seen before, with error type =2

Comment: Is it intentional that the commands are tokenized in different ways depending on which ProcessBuilder it is?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to gain some insight and maybe find a way. But only the 1st and 3rd were recognized as valid commands. And the arguments were ignored... so it just gave back a sort of "help" response.

Comment: try `new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli", "openGate", "--module", "" + col, "--locker", "" + row);`

Comment: @Zhuinden It works ! Can you send it in as an answer so i can mark this topic as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` expects you to split the command up into separate words, it won't break it up for you.  Also, you can't just "fire and forget" a `Process`, you have to continue interacting with it, in particular you need to either read or redirect the output and error streams from the process, and you need to `waitFor` the process to complete.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command1", "--param1", "--param2");

// option 1 - redirect output to a file
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("out.txt"));
Process p = pb.start();

// option 2 - send output to the Java process's own System.out
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();

// option 3 - read the output yourself in Java
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  // do something with the line
}

// and once you've dealt with the output in one of these three ways...
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

Something else to be aware of is that Java can only execute `.exe` files directly - if the command you want to run is a `.bat` then you need to use `cmd.exe` - there are many other examples of this in other questions.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not getting the error message any more :)
But nothing else happens as well...
Also, when i did not split it up, but only had to give 1 parameter instead of 2 (it was a different command, but the same software), it worked.

Comment: @SzabóBalázs I've added some more details - there's other things you have to do after you've called `start()`

Comment: The text output was very useful. Now i know, that process builder has executed the first command seperatly, without the rest. Than continued to execute every other bit seperatly.   (everything divided by the , ). Now the process builder is like this: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli", "openGate", "--module " + col, " --locker " + row);

Comment: So, basically it took the command like this "apmhalcli openGate". But it acted as if it did not get the 2 parameters. "--module 6" and "--locker 3" So, why did it not get the last 2 parts? I also tried every permutation of seperating them while sending. If "apmhalcli" and "openGate" are together, it is an error. But it doesn't make any difference to it, if i put the 2 parameters in different strings or in a single string.Sorry for my incompetence, I am fairly new to Java.

Comment: @SzabóBalázs each parameter needs to be a separate string, i.e. `new ProcessBuilder("apmhalcli", "openGate", "--module", col, "--locker", row)`

Comment: Yes, just 2 mins ago someone else commented it. And it worked. I thought the different type of data need to be seperate. But thank you, now i realize how this should work and it does. So a bit thanks to you  Ian Roberts and Zhuinden, for the help!!! =)